# MySQL Multiple queries into single one

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table like with the following rows:

```
id  |  event_type  |  occurance_date  |  ipaddress
```

I want to get the days, unique visits and total visits / day. This is pretty easy to do with 2 queries but I want to make only one.

So i thought
To get the days i can

```
SELECT DISTINCT(occurance_date) as day FROM statistics WHERE event_type = 'visit' 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 14;
```

To get unique visits / day

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(ipaddress)) as unique_visits FROM statistics WHERE occurance_date = '2011-05-11';
```

To get all visits / day

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as total_visits FROM statistics WHERE occurance_date = '2011-05-11';
```

The problem is how can I make a single query to return me the all the days, with unique_visits and total_visits.

(2011-05-11 should be replaced by date, it's just an example)

Any suggestion is more then welcomed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select count(*) as total_visits, count(distinct(s1.ipaddress)) as unique_visits 
FROM statistics s1 
WHERE event_type = 'visit'
GROUP BY occurrence
ORDER BY unique_visits;
```

**Annotated version:**

First we do a SELECT count(all rows)

```
select count(*) as total_visits,
```

Plus a count of the distinct ipaddresses

```
count(distinct(s1.ipaddress)) as unique_visits
```

From statistics, I've added an alias, but that's just out of habit. It is not needed.

```
FROM statistics s1
```

Remember you wanted only rows that had event_type 'visit'.
You also had some information need about that, but you did not want to filter those out, you just wanted to see them as separate items in the result.
So the only **filter** we have is `event_type`.

```
WHERE event_type = 'visit'
```

We group the result by occurrence date, if you leave this line out, you will only see one line. Put it back in to see the difference.

```
GROUP BY occurrence
```

And we order the results by number of visits, except I didn't want to rewrite `count(distinct(s1.ipaddress))` so I wrote the alias `unique_visits`; this is allowed *(and even encouraged in an `order by` clause.)*

```
ORDER BY unique_visits;
```

**Links:**
Group by, never mind about this myth part, just read the description of how group by works:
http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/debunking-group-by-myths.html
Count: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks. Can you please help me understand how you did it?

Comment: Wow, you've put some work into that, thanks a lot. I have another question thought. I want to get only the last 30 days, but in ASC order. So if I ORDER BY occurrence_date DESC LIMIT 30 , i get the last 30, but in DESC order, and if I change it to ASC i get the first 30 entries. Any ideas?

Comment: do: `select * from (select .... order by occurrence_date desc limit 30) order by occurrence_date asc;`

Comment: i have: `SELECT * FROM(SELECT count(*) AS total_visits, COUNT(DISTINCT(s1.ipaddress)) AS unique_visits, occurance_date 
FROM statistics s1 
WHERE event_type = 'visit'
GROUP BY occurance_date
ORDER BY occurance_date DESC LIMIT 30) ORDER BY occurance_date ASC;` , but I get `Every derived table must have its own alias`.

Comment: It seems adding an `AS statistics` in front of the last ORDER BY fixed the error.